# REST API, delete request, error with CORS specification or query?

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express, cors

Basically, i have had error with DELETE operation in REST api application on Node.js server and Angular 2 front end

Error message in browser:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:800/api/admin/deleteArticle?id=5f5244b8376ddd1d0c70ef52' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

> DELETE http://localhost:800/api/admin/deleteArticle?id=5f5244b8376ddd1d0c70ef52 net::ERR_FAILED

> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:800/api/admin/deleteArticle", ok: false, …}

Front end- sending (Angular):

```
public deleteArticle(articleId: string) {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams().set('id', articleId);
    const options = { params: httpParams };
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this.http.delete('http://localhost:800/api/admin/deleteArticle', options)
        .subscribe((serverResponse: any) => {
          console.log(serverResponse);
        });
    });
  }
```

Back-end server (Node.js):

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/adminRoutes');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Origin, X-Requested-Width, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  )
  next();
});

app.use('/api/admin', adminRoutes);
```

adminRoutes.js

```
const router = express.Router();

router.delete('/deleteArticle:id', checkAuth, adminController.deleteArticle);

// everything is OKEY with checkAuth middleware
```

adminController.js

```
exports.deleteArticle = (req, res, next) => {
    const articleData = req.query;
    console.log(articleData)
 }
```

It is look like CORS error but I registered in the setting DELETE operation (app.js) so that there must be no error :(

Could you help me to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Silly question: are you really using port 800? Seems, more often than not, 8000 is used. Could be the problem(?).

Comment: R. Richards, thanks for participation, everything is ok with port number, There are solution from Frost and it is working (cors library ), i think there must be some small configuration error, because it was working good before last Friday (I still will try to find it)

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors()); // Use this after the variable declaration

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/adminRoutes');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Origin, X-Requested-Width, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  )
  next();
});

app.use('/api/admin', adminRoutes);
```

Comment: Use this two lines `var cors = require('cors');` and `app.use(cors());`